# 4 piece Navigation Bar issues

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a navigation bar with 4 links that stays to the right, while keeping the logo on the left. How does one accomplish this task? My code is sort of a mess as I've been trying many different methods.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Wolfgang's Portfolio</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <a id="logo" href="home.html" alt="Wolfgang's logo">Wolfgang Hall</a>


    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="about-me.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-info.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #2a2c2b;
    font: 16px Josefin Sans; 
    color: #d9cb93; 
line-height: 24px;
} 

a:link {
    color: #d9cb9e; 
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #d9cb9e; 
 }

#container {
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto; 
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
}

#logo a:hover {
    color: #dc3522;
}

#header {
    width: 480px;
}

ul.nav {
   width: 500px;
   height: 30px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   background-color: #DC3522;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Cardo';
   position: relative;

}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 0 0; 
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9cb9e;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
}

.nav a:hover {
    background: #374140;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you want to float your logo to the left and float your nav to the right.

```
#logo {
  float:left;
}
ul.nav {
  float:right;
}
```

Don't float your nav links.

In addition to that, because you're <li>'s are displayed inline-block, make sure there are no white-spaces inbetween each one, or they will not fit. Otherwise you'll have to float each li 'left'.

Also, when you use floats you have to always clear them. You can use the method i've used in the fiddle, by adding a div and setting clear to 'both', or you can google "clearfix" and use that class whenever you have floated divs you need to clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/5176b7gk/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it pretty easily using floats. Here is a sample page that just displays a top menu, and you can see a suggestion of how to format your logo and navigation inside a div, which gives you more control of the menu as a complete UI element.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wolfgang's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="top_menu">
            <div class="branding">
                <a id="logo" href="home.html">Your Logo</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="about-me.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-info.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <!-- Rest of the page here -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- Container ends -->
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .branding {
            float: left;
        }
        .nav {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            float: right;
        }
        .nav li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```